# How to making Guix scripts portable across other UNIX-like systems given Guix's atypical file system structure?

Tags: shell, unix, exec, guix

Here is a trivial solution to the problem of writing a script on Guix.

```
#!/run/current-system/profile/bin/env -S guile -s
coding: utf-8
!#
(display "Hello, world!\n")
```

Notice that the path `/run/current-system/profile/bin/env` will not exist in other GNU systems such as Ubuntu or Debian.  So, how would we take advantage of UNIX's `exec` system call without editing the script on other systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the script as it is, on the other system (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu, etc.) make `env` available at the same location (you may need sudo)

```
mkdir -p /run/current-system/profile/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/env /run/current-system/profile/bin
```

Comment: I think we're converging on the fact that there's nothing better to do, that is, we really must know where `env` is and that's it.  Correct?  So I guess Guix systems present a new problem to the nightmare task of writing portable programs on UNIX-like systems.

Comment: Totally agree. However, this fix applied once would fix all the scripts.